# Getting pageLoad error in MicrosoftAjax.js

Tags: javascript, pageload, microsoft-ajax

I am writing an asp.net web forms website that requires users to login. 
I am experiencing some errors with the raiseLoad function in MicrosoftAjax.js after they have logged on.

MicrosoftAjax.js is loaded as a bundle

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/WebFormsJs") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

My BundleConfig file is

```
Public Class BundleConfig
    Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(ByVal bundles As BundleCollection)
        bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"))

        bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"))

        bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"))

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run my website on different browsers, I get different errors

- IE11 - Object doesn't support property or method 'pageLoad'
- Edge - SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'pageLoad'
- Chrome - Uncaught TypeError: window.pageLoad is not a function
- Firefox - TypeError: window.pageLoad is not a function

IE11 is the only browser that displays a popup asking if the user would like to debug the error (even though I have Disable script debugging ticked)

I have done numerous searches on google and bing for "Object doesn't support property or method 'pageLoad'" and I can find hundreds of "Object doesn't support property or method 'xxx'" pages where 'xxx' might be 'insert', 'includes', 'assign', 'startswith' etc but never 'pageLoad'.

I have also done numerous searches for "TypeError: window.pageLoad is not a function" and all the results refer to window.onload.

The resultant pages all seem to refer to an error in the developer's website code, not a third party javascript file.

I have even searched for "MicrosoftAjax.js pageLoad error" and "MicrosoftAjax.js error" but none of the results relate to pageLoad.

I suspect that this error is a very simple one in my web page that manifests as the errors I am getting but I have no idea where to even start looking.

I only have until January to resolve this issue so any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe trying to change the order of the files or bundles when referencing them?

Comment: @André I have tried all 6 possible sequences of loading the bundles but nothing changed. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my issue on the website below: -

[JavaScript pageLoad() for MasterPage and ContentPage](https://devio.wordpress.com/2009/02/22/javascript-pageload-for-masterpage-and-contentpage/)

Basically, I needed to add a pageLoad event to my master page: -

```
function pageLoad(sender, args){
    if (window.contentPageLoad) {
        window.contentPageLoad(sender, args);
    }
}
```

And replaced the following '$(document).ready' function with 'contentPageLoad' function on my content page: -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hyperlinkTest').tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "tooltip"
    });

    $('.hyperlinkMaint').tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "tooltip"
    });
});
```

with : -

```
function contentPageLoad(sender, args) {
    $(".hyperlinkTest").tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "tooltip",
    });

    $(".hyperlinkMaint").tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "tooltip",
    });
}
```

My error has not reared its ugly head since I added both pieces of code.